# Sending order details in hidden input fields?

Tags: php, e-commerce

I'm developing payment extensions for multiple php based eCommerce platforms for a company that has their own payment processor (they just take post request; do couple checks and process it toward a real payment gateway).

Their mechanism is plain and simple (and risky, I suppose). They want me to develop extensions that would, at the end, make a post call to their payment processor like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://pp.payment-processor-xyz.com">
<input name="order-amount" type="hidden" value="90.00" />
<input name="order-id" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input name="user-email" type="hidden" value="something@email.com" />
....
....
```

How do I tell them (or demonstrate, perhaps) that this is risky and that this is can easily be intercepted by a client and altered?

PS: Their processor has no access to merchant's cart inventory, that's plugin's job.

Comment: How does the e-commerce application verify that the transaction has been made? Does it just fire away the post request and hope for the best? Does it somehow get a confirmation? The system may be vulnerable, but from the information you have given it is not obvious.

Comment: Can you supply more details how the system works in a transaction from start to finish?

Comment: @Anders yeah, my plugin ( for any given e-commerce app [ magento, woocomm, etc ] ) would collect order details, validate, and create order before showing the above form ( just a button that says "Make payment at the gateway" ) at the e-commerce app. once a user clicks the submit button for the above form, s/he would be redirected to my company's payment processor who has no access to the e-commerce application or any other merchant's apis to verify any order details, they simply take the post data and pass (POST) it to a real payment gateway

Comment: But somewhere at the end your application must recieve some kind of notification that the transaction went through? Otherwise the customer wouldn't even need to go though with the payment! Couldn't that notification contain the amount paid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the details you have provided.Logic attacks can be conducted using burpsuite or any other proxy.The order amount can be changed to any arbitrary value.

P.s:- insufficient details about server side processing and checks.

Comment: server side of Merchant's? or the company's payment processor? if it's the company's processor then it doesn't matter, they don't have access to merchant's cart system inventory to verify POSTed amount or any other data Thanks for the burpsuite, i'll check it out n let you know

Comment: Then using any proxy you can change the amount value and if no check is performed on the payment.The amount you send should be processed.There is however a lot of information thats still missing like what happens after payment processing.

Answer (score -1):

It is very well possible using interceptors like burpsuite to change the values.

May be you can assign id numbers or tags to each product and then do a post based request which will then map the id to the assigned value in the server backend thus eliminating the possibility of any hacks.